# Unable to Send Sms using Telephony package on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sms, flutter-dependencies, telephony

I have been trying to write a simple flutter code and trying to send SMS using telephony. Sending Sms via the default SMS app works (telephony.sendSmsByDefaultApp()) but not sending directly from the app.

My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:telephony/telephony.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              sendSMS();
            },
            child: Text("Send SMS"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendSMS() async {
    final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
    bool? permissionsGranted = await telephony.requestPhoneAndSmsPermissions;
    print(permissionsGranted);

    await telephony.sendSms(to: "+92xxxxxxxxxx", message: "Hello, this is a test message.");
    print("SMS Sent");
  }
}
```

I have added the following required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing that `onPressed()` function in the `ElevatedButton()`, to an `async` function:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      await sendSMS();
    },
    child: Text("Send SMS"),
  )
```

And then change your `sendSMS()` function to return a `Future<void>`, instead of void:

```
Future<void> sendSMS() async {
    final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
    bool? permissionsGranted = await telephony.requestPhoneAndSmsPermissions;
    print(permissionsGranted);

    await telephony.sendSms(to: "+92xxxxxxxxxx", message: "Hello, this is a test message.");
    print("SMS Sent");
  }
 }
```

Comment: yes i tried that. It's working on my emulator but it's still not working on a real android device.

Comment: @umairalam did u solve this?